# Not able to clone gitlab repository

Tags: gitlab

I'm not able to clone a private repo from gitlab. Getting the below error

```
git clone ssh://git@localhost:10022/vnyapathi/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
ssh: connect to host localhost port 10022: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: If it's private... do you have access to it?

Comment: Yes, I do. Well is there any way to confirm? I was asked to commit to it. So I think I have access

Comment: Also I was able to dowload it manually. But clone gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

That means your public ssh key was not [properly registered to your GitLab server](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html) (if installed locally) or you need to replace `localhost` with its actual address:
Check the output of:

```
ssh -T git@localhost:10022
```

It should return a "Welcome to GitLab" message.

If it does, then check with the owner of the project if you are a [user of the project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/add-user/add-user.html#add-a-user) with the proper access level.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your URL. Can you double check the remote gitlab repo url again.

It should be of the format

```
git@gitlab.com:<username>/<remote-repo>.git
```

You can also refer to more guidance for cloning from [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/command-line-commands.html).